# When to throw runtime exception?

Tags: java, exception

Recently, I had interview with company and they gave me a coding problem. I was given program related to deck of cards and one of the methods was to shuffle the deck of cards. So I wrote the program as:

```
/** Shuffle the list of cards so that they are in random order 
 * @param d Deck of cards*/
public  static void shuffle(Deck d)
{
    if(d == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    List<Card> cards = d.getDeckOfCards();   // cards is basically Linked List.. cards = new LinkedList<Cards>()
    for(int i=0;i<cards.size();i++)
    {
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(52);
        Card c1 = cards.remove(randomNumber);
        Card c2 = cards.remove(0);
        cards.add(0, c1);
        cards.add(randomNumber,c2);
    }       

}
```

In the above code, I have thrown **IllegalArgumentException** which I'm most doubtful about. Under what conditions should actually throw a runtime exception? Should we actually throw runtime exception?

Thanks

Comment: "In the above code, I have thrown IllegalArgumentException  which I'm most doubtful about". Do you mean `throw new IllegalArgumentException();`?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with "failing early" here by throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, especially as passing `null` would be invalid. I'd probably consider using the version of `IllegalArgumentException` that takes a `String` to describe what went wrong though. If shuffle were a method of the Deck class that would remove any need to check for nulls.

Comment: From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html): *IllegalArgumentException: Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument*

Comment: Usually we throw `NullPointerException` for this case.

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` actually **is** a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: The code above can actually be improved by omitting the check for d == null, because then d.getDeckOfCards() will throw a NullPointer automatically if d is null. Add a javadoc comment '@throws NullPointerException if d is null' and everything is fine.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Should we actually throw runtime exception?

Yes, we should. Runtime exception serve a specific purpose - they signal programming problems that can be fixed only by changing code, as opposed to changing the environment in which the program runs.

> Under what conditions should actually throw a runtime exception?

When you detect an error with the way your class or method is used, throw a runtime exception.

Generally, there are two categories of situations when you need to throw a runtime exception:

- **Passing invalid parameter values** - This is the most common cause of runtime exceptions. Most parameter validation exceptions should be runtime exceptions. Java provides several subclasses to signal these specific problems.
- **Calling methods in a wrong sequence** - This is another common cause. When certain methods cannot be called until a class finishes initialization or some other preparatory steps, calls at the wrong time should cause runtime exceptions.

In this sense, your code is fine: it fits squarely in the first category, i.e. passing invalid parameter values. One thing I would do slightly differently is adding a message to say which parameter had an invalid value, but in your case it is not critical, because there is only one parameter there.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer does not explain why runtime exception should be thrown in those two cases? What is achieved by throwing them?
I also feel confused by this explanation of the difference between checked and runtime exceptions: checked ones signal the need " to change the environment in which the program runs" ... I wonder what the author meant - what is 'environment'?

Comment: Hi @AndreyM.Stepanov. A RuntimeException should be thrown in those two cases because it prevents the rest of the call stack from having to declare the exception. From the Javadocs: "RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary."

Comment: Should we log before throwing Runtime Exceptions. There is no need to catch runtime exceptions which are thrown from method hence there is no guarantee these will be logged.

Comment: @Viraj Logging of run-time exceptions is often done in the last-chance exception handler e.g. inside the `main` method.

Answer (score 18):

[`IllegalArgumentException` is, in fact, a subclass of `RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

It's just better to be a bit more specific, to help other programmers in the future. I would definitely prefer the `IllegalArgumentException` because it best describes what exactly went wrong, but really, either one would work.

Answer (score 4):

For example, if you're reading a file , and some IO error occurs, you're unlikely to recover from the error, so re-throwing the error to the top and consequently terminating the application isn't a bad course of action.

On the other hand, if you're anticipating recoverable errors then you should absolutely catch and handle the errors. For example, you may have users entering data in a form. If they enter data incorrectly, your input processing code may throw an exception (e.g. `NumberFormatException` when parsing a malformed number string). Your code should catch these exceptions and return an error the user, prompting for correct input.

When catching an exception and throwing `RuntimeException` instead, it is important to set the **original exception as a cause for the RuntimeException**. i.e.

throw new `RuntimeException(originalException)`.

Comment: Can you please clarify the final idea: why do you consider it to be a  good idea to 'throw new RuntimeException(originalException'?