# javascript What should a function return if initial conditions arent met?

Tags: javascript, function

My function should check, if the argument it receives is a 2d array with integers in a range. If argument meets those conditions, then the function should return an array. What should my function return otherwise? Should I throw an error or should I return something like false or 0? What's a good practice in this case?

Comment: It depends on the circumstances.

Comment: Agree with @str but I personally tend to inform my user what's going on.

Comment: The circumstances are that I was given an exercise as a part of recruitment process for an internship and when I asked them this question, they told me to follow the best practices. They also said that performance is important and throwing an error takes significantly longer than returning a value, right? Idk how often they want to throw in a bad array. At the moment my function just returns a 0 and I was wondering, if I should switch to throwing errors.

Comment: `if( is2d( array ) )` will work the same whether the function returns `0` or `false`, but I would insist on returning either `true` or `false`, not a number.

Comment: I worded my initial question badly, if the argument is "good", then the function should do stuff and return an array, not just true or false.

Comment: So return an empty array would be more reasonable. No?

Comment: If the objective of this function is to transform a 2d array into another array, then returning  `[]` might be the best choice. You can always throw an error higher up, if the result is an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering on the edited question:
I wouldn't do this with just a single function, instead structure it like this:

```
const is2dArray = array => array.every( item => Array.isArray( item ) && item.length === 2 );
const withinRange = (min, max) => input => input >= min && input <= max;

const mainFunction = arr => {
   if( Array.isArray( arr ) ){
      if( is2dArray( arr ) && arr.every( row => row.every( withinRange(0,5) ) ) ){
         const newArray = /* make the new array */;
         return newArray;
      }
   }
   return []; /* if desired and makes sense; or throw an error here;  */
}
```

If the objective of this function is to transform a 2d array into another array, then returning [] might be the best choice. You can always throw an error higher up, if the result is an empty array.

Comment: That's a good solution, but I was explicitly told to write one function to solve the problem, so this won't do. I have to choose between returning a value like false, -1 or 0 and throwing an error.

Comment: You can simply move the utility functions into the `mainFunction` body ;)

Comment: So I should return an empty array, if argument doesnt meet conditions, makes the most sense, I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your function is a testing function that returns a Boolean - it checks whether a condition is met - then it should return `true` for a true condition, and `false` for a false condition.

Comment: basically this. to be more specific, since the conditions you want to check is that the input is a 2d array meeting some other criteria as well, if it is not a 2d array in the first place, you should return `false`.

Comment: Yes @EugeneGhanizadehKhoub - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I worded my initial question badly, if the argument is "good", then the function should do stuff and return an array.

Comment: @smutny1221 in that case, the answer is yes you should throw an exception. take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538706/when-to-throw-runtime-exception) for example.